# Git with authentication but without ssh

Tags: django, git, authentication

I have the project to set up a git server for my school with a web interface to create repositories and display them. This web part will be handled by Django, which knows the users.

Now the problem: I want authentication to pull and push private repositories but I can't use SSH to handle that part (the IT guys don't want to do support on that). The HTTP protocol is read-only without "complexe WebDAV" ([according to the official doc](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html#The-HTTP/S-Protocol)) and use .htaccess as authentication. The problem with .htaccess is to manage them with Django: I tried to use a Django user's hash in it but it didn't work. And, finally, the Git protocol is read-write but it lacks authentication.

Summing up:

- I want authentication linked with Django's users database. (To avoid having multiple places with same data)
- No SSH
- Avoid WebDAV and .htaccess

With these constraints I found that rewriting the git daemon ([code on github](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/daemon.c)) to handle authentication would be an idea but I don't know for sure how a Git client would react to that.

If you guys have another idea or want to tell me how better it would be to use WebDAV/.htaccess/..., I will be glad to hear it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could setup an Apache server (even one with https like I do in [my config](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl)!), except you would ask your wsgi application to handle the authentication.

See "[Access Control Mechanisms](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/AccessControlMechanisms)", in the **[mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)**:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Top Secret"
AuthBasicProvider wsgi
WSGIAuthUserScript /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/auth.wsgi
Require valid-user
```

The auth.wsgi script can check the credentials against your Django users database.

That solution means calling the `git-http-backend` ([smart http transport](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/04/smart-http.html)), which is ore efficient than WebDAV.

Comment: Thanks ! Seems to be exactly what I wanted, let's try to implements it. :)